# Select rows Not Between particular date?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the Table **tblDate** with columns **id**, **startdate** and **enddate**.
I need to select the rows which is not between startdate and enddate. I had used the following query it gives the rows which is between the startdate and enddate.For example startdate=2014-02-24 , enddate=2014-02-28 the below query will give the respective id.

```
   select * from tblDate where '2014-02-25' Between startdate and enddate
```

How can I get the rest of the rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tblDate WHERE '2014-02-25' NOT BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```